# purchase dependent on previous purchase

Tags: product

I have google'd around on this and not finding any real leads here, anyone know how or more to the point the best way to make the purchase of one product only able after they have bought another regardless of if it's in the same order or not?

Answer (score 1):

There's no out of the box Magento way of doing this. It will require you to write some code depending on what kind of functionality you want.

Let's say you want to hide the *add to cart* button on the product view page in case a certain product is nog in cart.

```
$required_product = [ID of product required to purchase current product];

$item_collection = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->getCollection()
  ->addFieldToFilter('quote_id', Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuoteId())
  ->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $required_product);

if ($item_collection->count()) // Item is in cart
{
   // put here the add to cart butten
}
else // product not in cart
{
  $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($required_product);
  echo $this->__("Please purchase <a href=\"%s\">%s</a> first before adding this item to cart", $product->getUrl(), $product->getName());
}
```

On a side note: this is not very user friendly. I would advice you to make a bundled product out of this so the user has no other option then to add both items to cart.

Comment: thank you, I was more interested in maybe an extension that may have already been built but, well I guess I'll write one.  This is a help. Cheers

Comment: I haven't encountered one that does this but who knows, it might be out there. Don't forget to vote as answered if this solved your issue

Comment: well I'm going to give it some time before excepting that the answer is that there is nothing out there for this.  If I don't see something by the end of the week I'll close it out.  cheers